# How to hide or set location for hvplot subplots title

Tags: python-3.x, plot, holoviews, hvplot

My dataset is a simple one:

[image: Product volume by month]

I'm using python hvplot to draw subplots by simply giving a "col" statement"

```
    bar = df.hvplot.bar('month', 'volume', col = 'product', \
height = 200, width = 200, rot=90, logy = True, grid = True)
```

The plot looks like this:

[image: sample plot]

I want to hide the plot title area (dashline circled part) or move it to the bottom of plot. I searched the internet, but didn't find much clue. Appreciate if someone can help me out.

A side question, how do I specify bar fill color by product name? hvplot doesn't seems to support cmap.

Answer (score 1):

First, welcome to Stackoverflow! For the future, please provide a so-called MWE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Short answer:

```
df.hvplot.bar('x', 'y', row='z').opts(xaxis=False)
```

will remove what you call the "title".

Long answer:

hvplot returns Holoviews objects, see

```
import holoviews as hv
```

Some (if not most) customization options can only be accessed directly through Holoviews itself. In this case, since your provided the `col` parameter, it gives you a holoviews `GridSpace`, see here:http://holoviews.org/reference/containers/matplotlib/GridSpace.html

so what you call the "subplots title" is actually the axis of your GridSpace! And this is what you switch off using the `xaxis=False` call.

You can get inline help on available options via

```
hv.help(hv.GridSpace)
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are many ways to move the product labels down in your barplot:**

```
# import libraries
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
import hvplot
import hvplot.pandas

# create example dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'product': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
    'month': ['201801', '201802', '201803', '201801', '201802', '201803',  '201801', '201802', '201803'],
    'volume': [100, 125, 110, 85, 87, 96, 177, 167, 130]
})
```

**Possible solutions:**

```
# create barplot option 1
df.hvplot.bar(x=['product', 'month'], y='volume')

# or do it like this
df.hvplot.bar(x='product', y='volume', by='month')

# or create your barplot like this
hv.Dataset(df).to.bars(['product', 'month'], 'volume')
```

**This will result in the following plot:**
[image: barplot labels down]